# Suddenly losing connection to a kernel on JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-lab

My custom kernel on JupyterLab does not have "metadata" by default, so I add it manually to a kernel.json file to enable a variable list:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3 (mykernel)",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

After restarting the JupyterLab, the kernel works normally and I can use the variable list.  However, around 30 minutes later, I get a message saying that the kernel is "missing". As a matter of fact, the custom kernel disappears from the pull-down kernel menu on the JupyterLab. This error happens only after I edit the kernel.json file. Does anyone know why this problem happens?

Comment: Some logging information from the server from the time just before and after when it happens would be useful. Also anything logged to web console in browser too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this error.

In general, a directory where the `kernel.json` is located should also contain two PNG files (`logo-32x32.png` and `logo-64x64.png`) to display a logo of Python on the Jupyter Lab.
[image]

However, in my environment file, those images were missing, which caused the error to display the kernel. After I added the images, the problem has been resolved.